# Logarithms of fractions

Tags: logarithms

Is there a convention against having a fraction passed to a logarithmic function? The reason I'm asking is for my Calculus I class.

My teacher wants me to solve for x, and counts my answer as incomplete. Here's an example:
Solve for x:
    e^x = 1/2

My answer:
x = ln(1/2)

Teacher's answer:
-ln(2)

I understand the law where
ln(1/2) = ln(1) - ln(2)
technically making my answer and my teacher's answer both correct.

And thus my question. Should my answer be accepted as correct, or is there a convention against having fractions as an argument to a logarithmic function?

Thanks!

Comment: The only thing you have to make sure is that the argument of the logarithm is positive. So $\ln{\frac{1}{2}} = \ln{1} - \ln{2}$ is correct.

Answer (score 1):

$$\ln\left(\dfrac{a}{b}\right)=\ln a-\ln b$$

For your case $\begin{bmatrix}a \\ b\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1 \\2\end{bmatrix}$. Since $\ln 1=0$. We have:

$$\begin{aligned} x&=\ln(1/2)\\&=\ln1-\ln2\\&=-\ln2\end{aligned}\implies \ln(1/2)\equiv -\ln(2)$$

> Is there a convention against having fractions as an argument to a logarithmic function?

No there is no such convention. So yes your answer is equivalent to your instructor's. But here's a suggestion:  it's always better to simplify the expression further.